# Demonstration with Vandermonde's Identity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

**VANDERMOND’S IDENTITY:**

Let *m*, *n*, and *r* be nonnegative integers with r not exceeding either m or n. Then

$${m+n \choose r} = \sum_{k=0}^{r}{ {{m}\choose{r-k}} { {n} \choose {k} } }$$

The exercise asks to determine, using Vandermonde's identity, the value of *n* that makes the following true equality:

$${n+1 \choose 4} = {n \choose 3}$$

I believe that, since *r* = 4 > 1 = *m*, the formula can not be used. Am I right or is there some "generalized Vandermonde's identity" that validates the use of the formula in this case?

Comment: Which is the Vandermonde's identity? (We apply it for the $1\times 1$-matrix with the one entry $1$, then switch to the problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) holds if $m,n,r$ are all non-negative integers. (Without the restriction *$r$ is not exceeding either $m$ or $n$*.) In particular, the identity holds for $r = 4$ and $m=1$.

Note that for two integers $a,b \geq 0$ with $a<b$, we define
$${a \choose b} = 0,$$
since it is impossible to choose $b$ people from $a$ people.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot this important detail.